# Comparison Of Pointers

Tags: c++

I want to compare the memory address and pointer value of `p`, `p + 1`, `q` , and `q + 1`.

I want to understand, what the following values actually mean. I can't quite wrap my head around whats going on.

When I run the code:

- I get an answer of `00EFF680` for everytime I compare the adresss `p` with another pointer.
- I get an answer of `00EFF670` for everytime I compare the address of `q` with another pointer.
- I get an answer of `15726208` when I look at the pointer value of `p`.
- And I get an answer of `15726212` When I look at the pointer value of `p + 1`.
- I get an answer of `15726192` when I look at the pointer value of `q`
- And I get an answer of `15726200` Wehn I look at the pointer value of `q + 1`.

---

**Code**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int val = 20;
    double valD = 20;
    int *p = &val;
    double *q;
    q = &valD;
    cout << "Memory Address" << endl;
    cout << p == p + 1;
    cout << endl;
    cout << q == q + 1;
    cout << endl;
    cout << p == q;
    cout << endl;
    cout << q == p;
    cout << endl;
    cout << p == q + 1;
    cout << endl;
    cout << q == p + 1;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Now Compare Pointer Value" << endl;
    cout << (unsigned long)(p) << endl;
    cout << (unsigned long) (p + 1) << endl;
    cout << (unsigned long)(q) << endl;
    cout << (unsigned long) (q + 1) << endl;
    cout <<"--------" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Operator precedence.

Comment: and what's your precise question?

Comment: `int`egers on your machine are 4-byte long, that's why there's a difference of 4 bytes between the `p` and `p + 1` pointers, whereas `double`s are 8-byte long.

Comment: If you have a `type` and a pointer to it like `type* pointer;`, this expression will be (almost) always true: `((pointer + 1) - pointer) == sizeof(type)`.

Comment: @Jezor I want to compare p, p +1 , q , and q + 1. And Understand what the results mean.

Comment: @JerrySmith what for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few warnings and/or errors.

The first is that overloaded operator << has higher precedence than the comparison operator (on clang++ -Woverloaded-shift-op-parentheses is the flag).

The second is that there is a comparison of distinct pointer types ('int *' and 'double *').

For the former, parentheses must be placed around the comparison to allow for the comparison to take precedence.  For the latter, the pointers should be cast to a type that allows for safe comparison (e.g., size_t).

For instance on line 20, the following would work nicely.

```
cout << ((size_t) p == (size_t) (q + 1));
```

As for lines 25-28, this is standard pointer arithmetic. See the explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394767/pointer-arithmetic).

Answer (score 1):

As to your question:

> I want to compare p, p +1 , q , and q + 1. And Understand what the results mean.

If p is at address 0x80000000 then `p+1` is at address 0x80000000 + sizeof(*p). If *p is int then this is 0x80000000 + 0x8 = 0x80000008. And the same reasoning applies for q.

So if you do `p == p + 1` then compiler will first do the additon: `p+1` then comparison, so you will have `0x80000000 == 0x80000008` which results in false.

Now to your code:

```
cout << p == p + 1;
```

is actually equivalent to:

```
(cout << p) == p + 1;
```

and that is because `<<` has higher [precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) than `==`. Actually you should get a compilation error for this.

Another thing is comparision of pointers of non related types like `double*` with `int*`, without cast it should not compile.

Answer (score 1):

In C and C++ pointer arithmetic is very closely tied with array manipulation. The goal is that

```
int array[3] = { 1, 10, 100 };
int *ptr     = { 1, 10, 100 };

std::cout << array[2] << '\n';
std::cout << *(ptr + 2)  << '\n';
```

outputs two `100`s. This allows the language to treat arrays and pointers as *equivalent* - that's not the same thing as "the same" or "equal", see [the C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptrequiv.html) for clarification.

This means that the language allows:

```
int array[3] = { 1, 10, 100 };
int *ptr     = { 1, 10, 100 };
```

And then

```
std::cout << (void*)array << ", " << (void*)&array[0] << '\n';
```

outputs the address of the first element twice, the first `array` behaves like a pointer.

```
std::cout << (void*)(array + 1) << ", " << (void*)&array[1] << '\n';
```

prints the address of the *second* element of array, again `array` behaving like a pointer in the first case.

```
std::cout << ptr[2] << ", " << *(ptr + 2) << '\n';
```

prints element #3 of ptr (100) twice, here `ptr` is behaving like an array in the first use,

```
std::cout << (void*)ptr << ", " << (void*)&ptr[0] << '\n';
```

prints the value of `ptr` twice, again `ptr` behaving like an array in the second use,

But this can catch people unaware.

```
const char* h = "hello";  // h points to the character 'h'.
std::cout << (void*)h << ", " << (void*)(h+1);
```

This prints the value of `h` and then a value one higher. But this is purely because the type of `h` is a pointer to a *one-byte-sized* data type.

```
h + 1;
```

is

```
h + (sizeof(*h)*1);
```

If we write:

```
const char* hp = "hello";
short int* sip = { 1 };
int* ip = { 1 };

std::cout << (void*)hp << ", " << (void*)(hp + 1) << "\n";
std::cout << (void*)sip << ", " << (void*)(sip + 1) << "\n";
std::cout << (void*)ip << ", " << (void*)(ip + 1) << "\n";
```

The first line of output will show two values 1 byte (sizeof char) apart, the second two values will be 2 bytes (sizeof short int) apart and the last will be four bytes (sizeof int) apart.

The `<<` operator invokes

```
template<typename T>
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& stream, const T& instance);
```

The operator itself has very high precedence, higher than `==` so what you are actually writing is:

```
(std::cout << p) == p + 1
```

what you need to write is

```
std::cout << (p == p + 1)
```

this is going to print `0` (the result of `int(false)`) if the values are different and `1` (the result of `int(true)`) if the values are the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print the value of a pointer, you can cast it to `void *`, for example:

```
cout << static_cast<void*>(p) << endl;
```

A `void*` is a pointer of indefinite type.  C code uses it often to point to arbitrary data whose type isn’t known at compile time; C++ normally uses a class hierarchy for that.  Here, though, it means: treat this pointer as nothing but a memory location.

Adding an integer to a pointer gets you another pointer, so you want to use the same technique there:

```
cout << static_cast<void*>(p+1) << endl;
```

However, the difference between two pointers is a signed whole number (the precise type, if you ever need it, is defined as `ptrdiff_t` in `<cstddef>`, but fortunately you don’t need to worry about that with `cout`), so you just want to use that directly:

```
cout << (p+1) - p << endl;
cout << reinterpret_cast<char*>(p+1) - reinterpret_cast<char*>(p) << endl;
cout << (q - p) << endl;
```

That second line casts to `char*` because the size of a `char` is always 1.  That’s a big hint what’s going on.

As for what’s going on under the hood: compare the numbers you get to `sizeof(*p)` and `sizeof(*q)`, which are the sizes of the objects `p` and `q` point to.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a picture will help (For a 64bit machine)

[image]

p is a 64bit pointer to a 32bit (4byte) int. The green pointer p takes up 8 bytes. The data pointed to by p, the yellow int val takes up 4 bytes. Adding 1 to p goes to the address just after the 4th byte of val.

Similar for pointer q, which points to a 64bit (8byte) double. Adding 1 to q goes to the address just after the 8th byte of valD.

Answer (score 0):

The pointer values that are printed are likely to change on every execution (see [why the addresses of local variables can be different every time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34908728/why-the-addresses-of-local-variables-can-be-different-every-time) and [Address Space Layout Randomization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization))

- > I get an answer of 00EFF680 for everytime I compare the adresss p with another pointer.

  ```
  int val = 20;
  double valD = 20;
  int *p = &val;
  cout << p == p + 1;
  ```

  It is translated into `(cout << p) == p + 1;` due to the higher precedence of `operator <<` on `operator ==`.

  It print the hexadecimal value of `&val`, first address on the stack frame of the `main` function.

  Note that in the stack, address are decreasing (see [why does the stack address grow towards decreasing memory addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4560720/why-does-the-stack-address-grow-towards-decreasing-memory-addresses)).
- > I get an answer of 00EFF670 for everytime I compare the address of q with another pointer.

  ```
  double *q = &valD;
  cout << q == q + 1;
  ```

  It is translated into `(cout << q) == q + 1;` due to the precedence of `operator <<` on `operator ==`.

  It prints the hexadecimal value of `&valD`, second address on the stack frame of the `main` function.

  Note that `&valD <= &val - sizeof(decltype(valD) = double) == &val - 8` since `val` is just after `valD` on the stack. It is a compiler choice that respects some alignment constraints.
- > I get an answer of 15726208 when I look at the pointer value of p.

  ```
  cout << (unsigned long)(p) << endl;
  ```

  It just prints the decimal value of `&val`
- > And I get an answer of 15726212 When I look at the pointer value of p + 1.

  ```
  int *p = &val;
  cout << (unsigned long) (p + 1) << endl;
  ```

  It prints the decimal value of `&val + sizeof(*decltype(p)) = &val + sizeof(int) = &val + 4` since on your machine `int` = 32 bits

  Note that if `p` is a pointer to type `t`, `p+1` is `p + sizeof(t)` to avoid memory overlapping in array indexing.

  Note that if `p` is a pointer to `void`, `p+1` should be undefined (see [void pointer arithmetic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3377977/void-pointer-arithmetic))
- > I get an answer of 15726192 when I look at the pointer value of q

  ```
  cout << (unsigned long)(q) << endl;
  ```

  It prints the decimal value of &valD
- > And I get an answer of 15726200 Wehn I look at the pointer value of q + 1.

  ```
  cout << (unsigned long) (q + 1) << endl;
  ```

  It prints the decimal value of `&val + sizeof(*decltype(p)) = &valD + sizeof(double) = &valD + 8`